# Python 3 Trigger Callbacks on Implicit Value Changes

Tags: python-3.x, observer-pattern, python-descriptors

I want a `callback` to get called whenever a certain attribute of object `A` is changed.

I'm aware that this question is related to Observer Pattern and descriptors in Python. However, it seems descriptors could only detect explicit changes via dot access.

For instance:

```
class Observer(object):
    def __init__(self, callback=None):
        self.__callback = callback

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.__name = name
    
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        obj.__dict__[self.__name] = value
        self.trigger()
    
    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        return obj.__dict__.get(self.__name)
    
    def trigger(self):
        self.__callback()


def hello():
    print('hello')


class MyClass:
    data = Observer(hello)


a = MyClass()
a.data = [[1],2,3]
a.data.append(4)
a.data[0][0] = -1
```

In the above code, the callback is only called once for the initialization of the `data`. However, I want it to be called 3 times. I'm not tied to using descriptors but I do want the method to work on any data types, such as `list`, `dict` and etc.

Comment: you'd need to implement a proxy wrapper around whatever values you have which accepts all methods and defers to the underlying object -- but then how would you determine which methods / operators mutate vs which that don't (you can't in general know whether arbitrary method X on type Y caused a mutation or not)

Comment: What you said makes sense, thanks! Then I think the proxy could compare the pre-state and post-state of the value to determine if there is a mutation caused by an arbitrary method. It seems the question boils down to whether there is a away to detect arbitrary mutation then.

Comment: to do that you'd need to deep copy before and deep compare afterwards and there isn't a general (not all objects are copyable or deep copyable or equatable) or cheap way to do that (deep copy is expensive, deep equality can be expensive).  plus it's entirely possible that the state is stored off of the object (imagine a class wrapping a sqlite store for instance) where it'd be impossible to detect

Comment: If we put the overhead aside, is there a way to compare the entire states of the interpreter before and after a function call, to detect any potential mutations?

Comment: not really, I suspect you'll want to re-design whatever thing you're trying to do